# Remove visually similar images from folder

Tags: windows-xp, images, duplicate

I need a free application/tool to remove visually similar images from folder. Most of the tools available are free only for demo version(i.e limited to few results)Found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/152531/what-is-the-best-method-to-remove-duplicate-image-files-from-your-computer) ,but its script/code.

Comment: Have you checked Anti-Twin?

http://www.anti-twin.com/

Comment: @NoLifeKing I tried it right now, It works fine when number of images are less but otherwise its taking too much time.But yea till now this is the best I got.Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this related question: http://superuser.com/questions/30088/good-tool-for-finding-photo-duplicates-based-on-image-data?rq=1 Given that that question is closed as not constructive, I fear I'll have to close your question too